# Linux kernel in different systems

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I wanted to know if the exact same linux kernel is present in different systems like android phones, desktop, supercomputers etc. Are there no changes at all?

I got curious because [I saw that](https://www.kernel.org/) when a new linux kernel is released then it's not mentioned for which platform(system) it's being released. So it looks like whoever wants to use a linux kernel whether he wants to use it for smartphone or desktop computer or anything else has to use the exact same kernel. But I'm not too sure about it. Please help in clarifying if this question makes any sense.

Comment: https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2019/11/google-outlines-plans-for-mainline-linux-kernel-support-in-android/

Comment: Before you use the kernel, you need to compile it. That gives you a lot of control over what you want to include (and what not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kernels are indeed not released for specific systems, at least not from the “upstream” kernel project.

That doesn’t mean that there aren’t variations depending on the use case. The kernel has a large amount of configuration settings which can be used to adapt it to various scenarios, from small embedded systems to super-computers. In addition, kernels for embedded systems are commonly adapted by manufacturers, and most phones, embedded systems etc. use “BSPs” provided by their manufacturers; but the changes generally consist of additional drivers rather than core changes (and ideally shouldn’t be necessary).

Google recently announced that [they are working to use the mainline kernel for Android](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2019/11/google-outlines-plans-for-mainline-linux-kernel-support-in-android/). Some phones can already by used with the mainline kernel; see [Replicant](https://www.replicant.us/) for some examples. [Greg Kroah-Hartman](http://www.kroah.com/linux/), one of the main Linux kernel developers, has been advocating for this for many years, and he isn’t alone in this: the kernel’s development model encourages manufacturers to contribute their changes upstream, and the best long-term model for everyone is to use the mainline kernel with no changes other than configuration.